# Создать новую папку на сервере с помощью php

Tags: php

Как с помощью php, можно сделать новую папку на сервере?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартная функция - [mkdir()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mkdir.php), поможет вам.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir )700);
?>
```